# Can you tell me how to solve with process?

Tags: calculus

What formula can I use for this question?

[image]

Comment: Hint: what does it mean (mathematically) that two curves/lines are parallel to each other? What mathematical condition do they fulfill then?

Comment: What did you try? By the rules of the forum, you need to show some effort to solve the problem. Here are some leading questions to help you get started: does the curve increase or decrease? how about the line? At which point of the curve do the curve and the line change at the same rate?

Answer (score 2):

The slope of the line is $4$ so you want to find $x$ such that $(2e^{4x})'=4$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If two curves are parallel at a point, then they have the same slope at that point.